# ASP.NET MVC 4 connection string on server to mdf file on app_data for authentication db

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have mvc4 app on godaddy and I do not want to use their sql server database ....Actually I have exhausted my available number of databases on host
so i uploaded the authentication db file as mdf file to app_data folder but i cant connect the mdf file from my app
i used this conn string

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20151212082404;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20151212082404.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

it was working on local but not on server
so I changed it to this string

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=107.181.46.201\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication3-20151212082404;Integrated Security=SSPI ;user id=todd password=8534876523745;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication3-20151212082404.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but it does not work

how can i connect my .mdf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake is that i was use a **mysql database** on godaddy
all what I did is that i create an empty **sql server db** and edit my connection string with the new db name and user and passwore